# Creating old Nokia apps before JavaME support

Tags: c, assembly, sdk, embedded, nokia

I have some old Nokia phones, such as the **Nokia 3310.**

After searching online, I could only find guides for development relating to the new Nokia which supports JavaME. This is no good, as I have the older versions of the Nokia phones, not the remake.

How could I go about creating apps, and uploading them onto the phone? I have a good background in C and I really enjoy learning about internals. After learning the basics, I was thinking of making my own snake style game, before moving onto anything bigger.

Comment: Far as I know, it wasn't possible to develop custom programs to those old phones. What makes you think it is possible? Has anyone ever done it other than Nokia?

Comment: @Lundin I just turned on my old Nokia 3310 and I can see an option for applications and games, so somebody must have been releasing them? I did not understand your last question?

Comment: What I mean is: was it possible for anyone other than Nokia to make those? I think that wasn't possible until next generation or so, when GPRS was invented. You couldn't really connect to the internet in any meaningful way either prior 3G.